# ViewSet dreate error: "model" needs to have a value for field "field" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to define custom logic to  be executed when POSTing/creating a new API object but i'm receiving error: `"<Appointment: apitest>" needs to have a value for field "appointment" before this many-to-many relationship can be used`.

```
class AppointmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Appointment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                      IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    def create(self, request):
            serializer = AppointmentSerializer(data=request.DATA)
            return Response(serializer.errors,
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    def pre_save(self, obj):
            obj.service_recipient = self.request.user
```

Comment: Hi! I noticed you are using Django REST Framework 2.x. DRF 3 has been out for a bit and fixes quite a few bugs, you may want to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using **Django REST Framework 2.x**, which has very limited support for related object creation. Right now, you are trying to create a reverse-relationship (most likely through a foreign key or one-to-one), which Django REST Framework 2.x does not actually support.

**Django REST Framework 3.0** fixes a lot of the issues that we previously had with related object creation by making it so now it has to be manually implemented. You can find a lot more information about the changes in [the release announcement](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#writable-nested-serialization), and determine how it must be implemented in your case.